# Composition of permutations in cycle notation

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

For $p=(1\ 4\ 3\ 2)$, find $p^2$. The textbook states that the solution is $p^2=(1\ 3)(2\ 4)$.

Now I understand that $1 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 3$, and $2 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 4$, however, why must the result be written as the composition of two cycles instead of as just one cycle?

Comment: Because it actually is a composition of two cycles? For a given permutation, its cycle structure is what it is, and you can't change that. If it falls apart (so to speak) into two disjoint cycles, it is two disjoint cycles -- not a single cycle.

Comment: @zipirovich But for example, if $q = (1 \ 2\ 3)$, then $q²=(1\ 3\ 2)$. So the composition of two cycles does not necessarily lead to a result that is also the composition of two cycles

Comment: You are absolutely right -- in general it doesn't. And I didn't say that it does. But *in this particular example* (of the original question) it happens so.

Comment: @zipirovich Yes and that is what I'm confused about. I just started learning about permutations and cycles, so I'm probably missing something really simple; but when I do the composition of the two permutations, how do I know that I must write it as (1 3)(2 4) instead of, say ( 1 3 2 4)?

Comment: The other thing that I said is that we don't have any control over that. Once we calculate a permutation, it is what it is. And if it's a single cycle, or a product of two or three or whatever number of disjoint cycles, then that's how many disjoint cycles it has, and we can't change that. Note also that I'm talking about **disjoint** cycles, which is one of standard ways of writing permutations.

Comment: @zipirovich Thanks a lot, I didn't think it through. I was doing the calculation in a hurry and did it wrong... Should I just delete this question altogether or leave it up?

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete it. I'm actually, going to retype some of this as an answer -- just need a few minutes to finish typing.

Comment: Note that $p$ has order $4$ and $p^2$ has order $2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work appears to be correct, but you're a little confused as to how to represent the answer. Let's work it out for all inputs:
$$ 1\mapsto4\mapsto3, \quad 2\mapsto1\mapsto4, \quad 3\mapsto2\mapsto1, \quad 4\mapsto3\mapsto2. $$
But then, in the end of the day, the intermediate steps don't matter, so let's state just the end results of applying $p^2$ to each of the inputs:
$$ 1\mapsto3, \quad 2\mapsto4, \quad 3\mapsto1, \quad 4\mapsto2. $$
We can clearly see that there are two separate cycles here: $1$ and $3$ are mapped into each other, and $2$ and $4$ are mapped into each other. So using the **disjoint** cycles notation, we have to write that $p^2=(1\;3)(2\;4)$.

To address a follow-up question from our conversation above in the comments, this not the same as $(1\;3\;2\;4)$ because they act differently on some inputs. For example, $(1\;3)(2\;4)$ maps $3$ to $1$, while $(1\;3\;2\;4)$ maps $3$ to $2$.